# iPhone Autocomplete

Tags: iphone, uitableview, autocomplete, uitextfield, uitextview

I am creating an  iPhone application where I need to display autocomplete functionality for  one of the 5 textfield. What could be the best possible way to achieve this. For now I am showing a tableview on the didtextchange delegate method of UITextField. Kindly suggest me better way of doing this. Any suggestion will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the right thing. This is the generally followed practice. May be you can use a UIPicker but the iphone apps are all about giving users the experience they are familiar with. Trying something new may sometimes lead a user to the confusion and a bit frustration. Remember you should develop the application keeping the users in mind, who most of the time don't have technical knowledge and are not willing to explore things. They would like the UI which they are familiar with.

Hoping I am clear to you.