# Custom UITextField Autocomplete

Tags: iphone, ios

I want to implement a custom autocomplete functionality in a UITextField that will use the values provided by me, not the iPhone dictionary. Does any one knows how to do it or could point me to some resources?

Comment: I think similar question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198337/uitextfield-autocomplete-iphone-sdk). You may find this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values) useful.

Answer (score 13):

You can use this UITextField subclass:

https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField

The example shows you how to use an array as the data source for the autosuggest text.  The suggested text appears "ghosted", like you see in the address bar in a browser, as opposed to the speech bubble that iOS uses to autocomplete/suggest.

Comment: This one only supports left-alignment out of the box. You have to subclass it and write your own solution for right-aligned textfields.

Answer (score 4):

Here's [Another alternative](https://github.com/TarasRoshko/TRAutocompleteView). Fully customizable and configurable.

Answer (score 2):

Here's something same that I come across.

http://www.radulucaciu.ro/iphone-autocomplete-class/5/

Answer (score 0):

I've created a UITableViewController that you can add to your class very easily. The code is located here:

https://github.com/raulzito234/AutoCompleteTableViewController