# AutoFiltering table for UITextView

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

How can we create auto filtering table box for UITextView.
like below:

[image]

kindly let me know, if any example or source code is available.

Comment: I think similar question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198337/uitextfield-autocomplete-iphone-sdk). You may find this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values) useful.

Comment: Check this tutorial [http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/autocompletiontableview](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/autocompletiontableview) Hope it helps you..