# Autocomplete UITextField

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to auto complete a text field from a custom value

Having researched Google and SO here [UITextField Autocomplete - iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198337/uitextfield-autocomplete-iphone-sdk)

I tried this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

    if ([string isEqualToString:@"Fac"]) {
        _clientField.text = @"Factory";
    }

    return YES;
}
```

Problem is I get no predicted value entered `Factory`, just the typed value `Fac`

EDIT

Tried this based on answers...

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

if ([string isEqualToString:@"Fac"]) {
    _clientField.text = [_clientField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range
                                                   withString:@"Factory"];
  }

  return NO;
}
```

Still the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked your sample code and the text field's delegate is not set.

You can set it in your view controller using

```
_clientField.delegate = self;
```

Additionally you need to use a slightly different method to get the text which the users sees. Something like this:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *currentString = [textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    if ([currentString isEqualToString:@"Fac"]) {
        textField.text = @"Factory";
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

Note that you probably want to fine tune this a bit, since it e.g. also autocompletes when the user deletes text. But this should get you on the right track.

Comment: Thank you!, been wrestling with this for ages! Sorted at last!

Answer (score 7):

Sounds like HTAutocompleteTextField will do the job:

https://github.com/hoteltonight/HTAutocompleteTextField

You basically just need to give it an array of values as the autocomplete data source, and it will make the suggestions in the text field as the user types.

Answer (score 2):

You should have tried to `NSLog` `string` it always returns the last character the user inputs (except if you copy/paste a string: in this case your code works).

Actually, doing what you're trying to do is not as straightforward as it seems to be. 
Here what I came up with:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string
{
    NSLog(@"string: %@", string);

    NSString *currentText = textField.text;
    NSString *nextText = [currentText stringByAppendingString:string];

    if ([nextText isEqualToString:@"Fac"])
    {
        textField.text = @"Factory";
        return NO;
    }
    return YES;
}
```

If you don't build the nextText yourself then the autocompletion will be delayed. If you only check the value of textField.text for instance, and that you type "Fac" the completion will occur on the next character input.
When you autocomplete the field you have to return NO also so the `string` is not added at the end of the text field (F -> Fa -> Factoryc, you don't want that). So you say that textField should not change characters in range... And YOU change the textField value yourself.

Hope this will help you to understand what's going on in this `UITextFieldDelegate` method.

Comment: Just appending the string is not correct, since the user might insert the char at a different place. You need to replace the given range in the string instead.

Comment: @frenetischapplaudierend You are right. I didn't think about that.

Comment: It does not handle when deleting by backspace. It makes impossible to delete Factory from the textfield

Comment: You are right @Tom. To do things properly you should definitely use this method (https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:) instead of simply appending string. And you should also check for an empty string to handle the deletion properly. You also need to understand how range behaves in the different use cases such as appending, deleting, pasting, inserting, selecting and replacing.

Comment: I don't think the accepted answer works when deleting too. Doing autocompletion correctly requires more code and this delegate method behavior can be tricky to understand. My answer was to demonstrate that returning NO, lets you control the text replacement on your own.

Comment: And one last thing. You should check existing libraries (if you haven't already) to see if one already suits your needs. Autocompletion is a common feature and except if you have some specific requirements you should not be reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 1):

You can also have a look at this control ([NHAutoCompleteTextField](https://journeytoios.wordpress.com/2015/01/03/nhautocompletetextfield/)). In the example source code in the given link, you will see the search list filters as the user types.

`NHAutoCompleteTextField` is easy to integrate:

```
#import "NHMainHeader.h"

autoCompleteTextField = [[NHAutoCompleteTextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, width, 18)];  // 18 - example height
[autoCompleteTextField setDropDownDirection:NHDropDownDirectionDown];
[autoCompleteTextField setDataSourceDelegate:self];
[autoCompleteTextField setDataFilterDelegate:self];
```

and flexible to do customization as per your need. for example, create cell as per you need here:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)autoCompleteTextBox:(NHAutoCompleteTextField *)autoCompleteTextBox cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
```

Adjustable for the given direction of drop down.

```
typedef enum
{
    NHDropDownDirectionUp,
    NHDropDownDirectionDown

} NHDropDownDirection;
```

This control also offers some good extension functions that will help to deal with other UIs as well.

```
#import "UIView+NHExtension.h"
#import "UILabel+Boldify.h"
```