# autocomplete textfield swift

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swift3

I am using google maps and have a custom list of places. I want to add a textfield with autocomplete over my map. How would I do this?

```
"Places" : {
"15th_Street" : true,
"25th_Street" : true,
"Avalanche" : true,
"Beacons" : true,
"Bird_Rock" : true,
"Blacks_Beach" : true,
"Cardiff_Reef" : true,
}
```

Is there a way I can place a search bar and table view over the map to search places? What would this look like? I can't seem to put a text field over the maps or find a good example of autocomplete.

Comment: You'll want to create a custom search bar with a tableView overlay for your page. Then you can search through your `Places` and auto populate the `tableView` - When you click the result in the view you send the data where you need it. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zgP_VHhkroE) is a video that will help you learn the search bar steps.

Comment: There are thousands of examples of how to implement UITextField autocomplete on SO and the internet. Do a google search. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14384638/autocomplete-uitextfield) and [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338900/uitextfield-autocomplete). Marking as duplicate because there's an enormous amount of information about autocomplete. However, you actually asked two questions so if you can update it with ONE specific question, you may get an answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UITextField Autocomplete - iPhone SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3198337/uitextfield-autocomplete-iphone-sdk)

Answer (score 0):

You can cast `json` to `array` and use this [GitHub library](https://github.com/apasccon/SearchTextField)